# Github and Fogbugz

Tags: git, github, fogbugz

So we have integrated fogbugz and github, the actual mechanism seems to work.  (i.e. when pushing the "test" button on github, the message "payload delivered" is shown)  Unfortunately, cannot find the documentation on what to put in the commit message to tie the bug to the commit.

I have tried

```
git commit -am 'fixing 97047'
git push origin
```

and

```
git commit -am 'fixing #97047'
git push origin
```

Neither seems to work.  Would love to know what I'm missing - links to documentation would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The case number should be of the form:

```
\b((FogBug[sz]|Case|Bug[zs]*(?:ID)*):(\d+)
```

so

```
   FogBugz:1234
   FogBugs:1234
   Case:1234
   Bugz:1234
```

should all work.

I use  FogBugzId:1234

Comment: The source for the FogBugz service hook is [here](https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/services/fog_bugz.rb).

Comment: Updated link to FogBugz service hook source code: https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/lib/services/fog_bugz.rb

Answer (score 1):

The URL to the source code has changed to https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/lib/services/fog_bugz.rb

Also, the RE has changed to:

```
/\s*(?:Bug[zs]*\s*IDs*\s*|Case[s]*)[#:; ]+((\d+[ ,:;#]*)+)/i)
```

Which means, for example the word "FogBugz" will no longer work in the check-in comment. It will have to be something like "Bug IDs:123" or "Case:123" along with the FogBugz case number in order to be recognized.

Comment: Also multiple cases are supported: `Cases:#123,#456,#789,#101112`